# Convert typical form of list to another form of the list Scala

Tags: scala

I'm a beginner in Scala I have a list I want to convert one form of the list to another form of the list in Scala.Any help will be appreciated

Input

```
List("TyCd->HKT", "TyCd->KA1", "TyCd->1IF", "TyCd->FVT", "TyCd->VDT", "TyCd->VSD", "TyCd->T1S", "TyCd->T9T")
```

Excpect output

```
List("HKT", "KA1", "1IF", "FVT", "VDT", "VSD", "T1S", "T9T")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to remove `"TyCd->"` from each element, use `stripPrefix`:

```
list.map(_.stripPrefix("TyCd->"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val x = List("TyCd->HKT", "TyCd->KA1", "TyCd->1IF", "TyCd->FVT", "TyCd->VDT", "TyCd->VSD", "TyCd->T1S", "TyCd->T9T")
```

If you don't want to hard code `TyCd`, then there are may other options to do this.

```
scala> x.map(_.split("->")(1))
res2: List[String] = List(HKT, KA1, 1IF, FVT, VDT, VSD, T1S, T9T)

scala> x.map(_.split("->").drop(1))
res3: List[Array[String]] = List(Array(HKT), Array(KA1), Array(1IF), Array(FVT), Array(VDT), Array(VSD), Array(T1S), Array(T9T))

scala> x.map(_.split("->").drop(1).head)
res4: List[String] = List(HKT, KA1, 1IF, FVT, VDT, VSD, T1S, T9T)
```

In my opinion this is the safest approach

```
scala> x.map(_.split("->").drop(1).headOption).flatten
res6: List[String] = List(HKT, KA1, 1IF, FVT, VDT, VSD, T1S, T9T)
```

Hope this helps.